# Cast IWebdriver mock object to IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mocking, selenium-webdriver

How to convert `IWebdriver` mock object to `IJavaScriptExecutor`?

My code:

```
private Mock<IWebDriver> _mockBrowserDriver;
_mockBrowserDriver = new Mock<IWebDriver>();
var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor) _mockBrowserDriver;
```

Outcome:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IWebDriverProxy' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish here? `IJavaScriptExecutor` doesn't inherit from `IWebDriver` and vice versa. From the decompiled sources, here are the signatures:

```
public interface IWebDriver : ISearchContext, IDisposable {}

public interface ISearchContext {}

public interface IJavaScriptExecutor {}
```

If you want to perform a cast on a mocked instance, you'll need to use the `Object` property, which is of the actual type being mocked, as in:

```
var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor) _mockBrowserDriver.Object;
```

In this instance, you'll still get an invalid cast exception.

As an aside, why are you trying to mock `IWebDriver`? As it tends to be used for acceptance testing, are you trying to unit test your acceptance test code? If not, are you actually using `IWebDriver` in your production code?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by adding below statement

```
_mockBrowserDriver.As<IJavaScriptExecutor>();
```

Thanks to Charles.
Thanks to levelnis for damn quick reply, I was amazed!!!

1. Yes I am writing a unit test case by preparing the mock objects.
2. Unit test cases for testing the custom selenium actions.